# steam has installed, but will now not open

Tags: steam

When I try to run steam from the terminal i get this output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I'm very new to linux, but I've tried to uninstall steam, purge steam, and then reinstall, but have found no success.

Outputs:

sudo lshw -C display:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fe000000-fe07ffff
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1401 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 3483 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Also, my graphics card is a gtx 960

Comment: Woke up just a bit ago, hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Which driver did you install? Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: I unfortunately get no output, and the file name for the driver I installed is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30.run, which was out of NVIDIA's site.

Answer (score 0):

as i know steam needs the 32-bet libraries to work.

to install them Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

then copy past this to it:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

press enter and enter your password and wait till it finishes then copy past this to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that restart your computer and try steam again.

---

**Note: read the whole answer before processing.**

As the above attempt didn't work what you need to do is this.

In terminal

```
sudo apt-get instal inxi
```

then copy past `inxi -G` and read the output to see if your graphic card supports GLX

the output will look like this:

[image]

If your graphic card supports GLX then proceed by:

copy past this to a terminal:

```
export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
glxgears
```

this is the standard opengl test program.

After running this command it won't work just like steam, but you'll see which opengl library it's trying to load. assuming that /usr/local/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0 is the one trying to loud you'll have to do this.

copy past this to a terminal:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/you'r-graphic-card-drivers/libGL.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

When you'r-graphic-card-drivers is the the drivers that you have installed for your graphic card, and /usr/local/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0 should be replaced by the one you get trying to loud in the first test.

By this your pointing your graphic card driver to run the appropriate opengl library.

Comment: I had to look up some more stuff to get ia32 working, but after i successfully installed that, updated, and restarted, steam still didn't work. I still get the same output from trying to launch through console as well

Comment: This must be a wierd problem, but glxgears does work, and also those files aren't in those directories on my system. I feel like it might have something to do with that I installed my graphics drivers manually, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: Installing the drivers manually effect the a symbolic link pointing at the right opengl library, and i told you this files doesn't have to be in the same direction all you have to do is to put your direction instead of my direction and you'll be good to go, try it.